# How to get current position from media player list in VLCJ 3.X?

Tags: media-player, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm working on java and using VLCJ 3.X (EmbeddedMediaPlayer and MediaPlayerList classes). I need to do skip in the playlist on released (mouseevent) video slider (JSlider). How to get current position from media player list in VLCJ 3.X?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your MediaListPlayer via the MediaPlayerFactory, and you want access to the associated MediaPlayer, you need to create that MediaPlayer via the same factory, then invoke mediaListPlayer.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer).

If instead you are using EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent, there is a getMediaPlayer() method you can use.

You then can invoke whatever methods you want as normal on the mediaPlayer instance you have - such as adding a listener to be notified of position events, or by querying the media player for its position.

This API has improved a lot with vlcj-4.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. mediaListPlayerFinished, nextItem, stopped. These are the 3 events supported by the listener. Can you please help me to get a way to find the exact seek time?